# DateTime - Expand monthly Data to daily based on date range in row

Tags: python, datetime, ms-access, time

My data looks like the following:

| GroupingID | StartDate | EndDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2017-04-01 | 2017-04-30 |
| 2 | 2017-05-01 | 2017-05-30 |
| 3 | 2017-06-01 | 2017-06-30 |
| 4 | 2017-07-01 | 2017-07-30 |
| 5 | 2017-08-01 | 2017-08-30 |
| 6 | 2017-09-01 | 2017-09-30 |
| 7 | 2017-10-01 | 2017-10-30 |
| 8 | 2017-11-01 | 2017-11-30 |
| 9 | 2017-12-01 | 2017-12-30 |
| 10 | 2018-01-01 | 2018-01-30 |
| 11 | 2018-02-01 | 2018-02-30 |
| 12 | 2018-03-01 | 2018-03-30 |

**How can I expand the row values to daily data while keeping the GroupingID?
So desired result would be. MS Access would be preferred - Python is also fine.**

| GroupingID | StartDate | EndDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2017-04-01 | 2017-04-01 |
| 1 | 2017-04-02 | 2017-04-02 |
| 1 | 2017-04-03 | 2017-04-03 |
| 1 | 2017-04-04 | 2017-04-04 |
| 1 | 2017-04-04 | 2017-04-05 |
| 1 | 2017-04-05 | 2017-04-05 |
| 1 | 2017-04-06 | 2017-04-06 |
| 1 | .... | ... |
| 2 | 2017-02-01 | 2017-02-01 |
| 2 | 2017-02-02 | 2017-02-02 |
| 2 | 2017-02-03 | 2017-02-03 |

Comment: Please share what you have tried so far

Comment: 2018-02-30 That was a heluva day

Comment: Anyway, consider handling issues of data display in application code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a *Cartesian* (multiplying) query to generate this:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
    GroupingID, 
    10*Abs([Deca].[id] Mod 10)+Abs([Uno].[id] Mod 10) As Sequence,
    DateAdd("d",[Sequence],[StartDate]) AS [DateStart],
    DateAdd("d",[Sequence],[StartDate]) AS [DateEnd]
FROM 
    GroupDates,
    MSysObjects AS Uno, 
    MSysObjects AS Deca
WHERE 
    DateAdd("d",10*Abs([Deca].[id] Mod 10)+Abs([Uno].[id] Mod 10) ,[StartDate]) <= [EndDate]
```

Of course, only valid dates are allowed, thus your *2018-02-30* must be adjusted to *2018-02-28* leaving not 360 but 358 generated records.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way would be to group by "Month - 3", assuming that you're not actually looking to exclude days that are the 31st of the month and create new ones in February.

For example:

```
SELECT MONTH(DATE_SUB(tmp.`date`, INTERVAL 3 MONTH)) as `GroupingID`,
       DATE_FORMAT(MIN(tmp.`date`), '%Y-%m-%d') as `StartDate`,
       DATE_FORMAT(MAX(tmp.`date`), '%Y-%m-%d') as `EndDate`
  FROM (SELECT DATE_SUB(DATE_FORMAT(Now(), '%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00'), INTERVAL num.`id` DAY) as `date`
          FROM (SELECT (h*100+t*10+u+1) as `id`
                  FROM (SELECT 0 h UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) a,
               (SELECT 0 t UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) b,
               (SELECT 0 u UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) c) num
         WHERE num.`id` <= 1000) tmp
 WHERE tmp.`date` BETWEEN '2019-04-01 00:00:00' AND DATE_SUB('2020-04-01 00:00:00', INTERVAL 1 SECOND)
 GROUP BY `GroupingID`, tmp.`date`
 ORDER BY `GroupingID`, `StartDate`;
```

***Note:** the sub-query to generate days is for illustration purposes only, as source data is not available.*

This will return 366 rows as you require. However, by removing the grouping on `date`, you will see just 12 rows. If the source data has gaps in the date, you may need to pad it with a `UNION`, then `GROUP` on dates.

Comment: That's not valid Access SQL. Access doesn't allow unioning queries that don't reference a table, and `DATE_SUB` and `DATE_FORMAT` are not valid functions in Access SQL.

Comment: Note that modern date time stamps allow micro second values, so it's better practice to say '< 00:00:00'

Comment: Indeed. I saw the MySQL tag and went with that.